# Not sure which site to ask this on (concerns electronic devices)

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

I recently acquired an LG-brand multi-region DVD player, and I'm trying to find a compatible TV set to hook it up to- can anyone inform me on what or where to look?

Comment: There was once *[Electronic Gadgets](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets)*.